# How to intentionally slow down the emulator?

Tags: android, performance, android-emulator

This question goes the opposite direction than the usual about Android emulators.

My Android instrumentation tests (using Espresso against the RxJava-based app) run just fine on my development machine, but they occasionally fail in the build server.

My build server has a slower hardware than my machine. I think this is causing the actual Espresso checks to be performed before the background tasks have been completed. I'm aware that Espresso, by default, does not wait for RxJava schedulers (io() and computation()) to complete, so that may be the reason.

There are several ways to make Espresso aware of RxJava schedulers, but before implementing them I want to reproduce the problem on my machine.

I've tried disabling hardware acceleration to no avail.

In the configuration you can set the network speed and latency, but in this case I'm interested in throttling down CPU speed. There is no network involved in the failing tests.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your Android stack, but playing the devil's advocate, what would happen if a real world Android device ran as fast as the emulator, e.g. a high performance tablet?  I think you should not rely on speed to resolve a possible race condition in your code.

Comment: Indeed there should be a race condition somewhere, but I'd like to create an environment where it can occur more frequently, so that I can better analyze it and find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to edit configuration of your Emulator in AVD Manager, I just decreased RAM and Cores number and my tests started to fail more often:)

[image]

Comment: In case you have a fast CPU. Open energy options of windows go to your current energy plan, go to advanced, go to Processor power managment, then to Maximum processor state and set it to 5 or 10%. This will really slown down the Emulator that uses 1 CPU only. The i9-9900 CPU will throttle down from 4.8 Ghz to 0,77 GHz. This helped us quite alot to test timing related bugs in emulators which failed on the CI but not on the local machine.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to slow down the Android emulator, and even it that was possible, it won't expose more race conditions because both "parts of the race" are slowed down together, in this case Espresso and RxJava's background tasks.

It's better to focus instead on reproducing locally the same environment where the issue occurred.

Comment: it could help expose problems when the user can perform some actions faster than the UI can react